# python change the date format using strftime

Tags: python, date-format, strftime

In python how do i change the format of the date i made Subtract between two dates:

```
lease_expiry_date = '{}'.format(t.lease_expiry_date.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
lease_commencement_date = '{}'.format(t.lease_commencement_date.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
years = t.lease_expiry_date - t.lease_commencement_date
p.add_run('{}'.format(years))
```

and the result was:

```
358 days, 0:00:00
```

i just want to show 358 days using strftime

Comment: Can you give the input date time format so can find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object `years` is in Python a timedelta object, so you can specify which fields are of interest, e.g.:

```
'{}'.format(years.days())
```